# Typed dispatch with React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

After the official [tutorial](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start) I don't really understand how to properly dispatch an update with `react-redux@8.0.5`.

My setup looks like this:

```
export const mySlice = createSlice({
  name: 'MyItem',
  initialState: { field1: 'hello, world', field2: 0 },
  reducers: {
    setField: (state: { field1: string; field2: number }, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.field1 = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    myItem: mySlice.reducer,
  },
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Inside of a component, I'm struggling with the dispatch:

```js
const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch();

// Resembles the `dispatch(increment())}` from the offical example, but I get a type error and I can't pass my update data.
// Additionally, the signature looks wrong (it looks like a reducer)
dispatch(mySlice.actions.setField());
// Since the signature doesn't match, TypeScript complains with `Void function return value is used`
dispatch(mySlice.actions.setField('newValue')) 
// TypeScript won't complain, but it doesn't seem like I could pass my update this way
dispatch(mySlice.actions.setField);
// TypeScript won't complain, but it's neither typed nor the recommended approach anyway
dispatch({ type: 'Idontexist', someValue: "hey" });
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit:
The solution seems to be to use deconstructioning pattern:

```js
export const {setField} = mySlice.actions;
...
dispatch(setField('newValue'))
```

But I've no clue why that's working while accessing `dispatch(mySlice.actions.setField('newValue'))` directly doesn't.

Comment: Could you double check your `mySlice` import? It should import object created by `createSlice`, but you don't export it in your example

Comment: @Evgeny You're right, I fixed the export. Truth be told, all the code resides in the same file anyway (since it's just a quick-and-dirty example). ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export it correctly

```
export const {setField} = mySlice.actions;
```

now you can import it and dispatch(setField())

Comment: That did the trick! Can you explain why the destructuring `{setField}` is any different from the direct property access `mySlice.actions.setField`?